# Is there a way to evaluate from top of buffer to point?

Tags: ess, eval

While doing statistical work in ESS, I often want to evaluate everything from the top of buffer to point. This is to make sure that my analysis is reproducible (i.e. script can be run from top to bottom and gives the right result).

Is there a way to do this in ESS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `ess-eval-buffer-from-beg-to-here` (bound to `C-c <C-up>` by default).

I found this using `M-x apropos "ess eval"`.

Comment: Thanks! I just figured this out myself with suggestions from `helm`. Thanks for explaining how to get to the answer as well -- very helpful for beginners.

Comment: @Heisenberg Even better! Helm's implementation for `describe-function` is pretty handy